# How to create a project in Jenkins to run Job-2 after 10hrs from Job-1 completion time. Job-2 should take the same parameter input from Job-1?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

How to create a project in Jenkins to run Job-2 after 10hrs from Job-1 completion time.Job-2 should take the same parameter input from Job-1?

Answer (score 0):

You could, Use the build step

```
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/
```

to kick off your job 2 from job 1, passing the same params down. Nest this step within the catch of a try/catch, within a timeout block

```
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-timeout-code-enforce-time-limit
```

This way, when the timeout expires you catch it failure and instead kick off your job. Make sure you do not use the timeout step inside a node step so that you do not consume an executor.

So something like this:

```
node {
    //do job 1 tasks
}
timeout(time: 10, unit: 'HOURS') {
    try {
        // Do nothing? Maybe have an input step allowing cancellation?
    } catch (err) {
        // Timeout expires, execute next build
        build job: 'Job2', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param', value: params.PARAM1]]
    }
}
```

There are probably better ways to achieve this, but this atleast allows you to not be on an executor (using shell wait would require an executor)

Comment: Job 1 would be pending completion until job 2 completes in this solution.